# Edit a file inside war file in a docker container

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables, war

I have a docker image based on [`openjdk:8-jre-alpine`](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/) base image. I execute a war file inside the container with `java -jar ...`. My war file serves a web application and there's a file inside my war file `conf.json` where I have some configuration setups. I want to modify some of the configurations based on the environment variables of the docker container.

For example, I have a field for `"gateway_url":"some_url"`, which I need to change to `"gateway_url":"${gateway_url}"`. If this configuration file wouldn't have been inside the war file, I would've simply executed something like

`awk -v val="$gateway_url" '{gsub("some_url",val);print}' > conf.json`

in my entry point script to edit the `conf.json` file. In this case, I cannot access the configuration file directly because it is inside the war file.

How do I resolve this problem?

#### constraints

I don't want to use `jar` utility inside my container to update a file inside the war file because it increases the size of my container substantially (it isn't there by default and comes with whole JDK installation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

This is what I did in my entry point script:

```
zipedit(){
    echo "Usage: zipedit archive.zip folder/file.txt"
    curdir=$(pwd)
    unzip "$1" "$2" -d /tmp
    cd /tmp
    content=$(cat "$2")
    rm -f "$2"
    echo "$content" | awk -v gat="$GAT_URL" -v tam="$TAM_URL" -v prom="$PROMPT_URL" -v ecm="ECM_URL" \
    '{gsub("gat_url",gat);gsub("prompt_url", prom);print}' > "$2" &&
    zip --update "$curdir/$1"  "$2"
    # remove this line to just keep overwriting files in /tmp
    rm -f "$2" # or remove -f if you want to confirm
    cd "$curdir"
}

zipedit application.war base/conf/conf.json
```

It uses both `unzip` and `zip` utilities. I had to install `zip` using `apk add zip` first, and then I'm able to add the environment variables to a file inside a war file in docker container.